# Counting decompositions of an integer into a sum of k numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have an integer $n$, I decompose it as a sum of $k$ integers ($k$ is fixed in advance)
$$
n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k
$$
and I want to count the number of multisets with $k$ elements $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$ that realize the condition.

Is there a good way to find out the number in general given $n$ and $k$?

---

**Example**:
$n=4$, $k=3$
we have these decompositions

- $4=4+0+0$
- $4=3+1+0$
- $4=2+2+0$
- $4=2+1+1$

so in total we have $4$ multisets, $N(4,3)=4$.

Comment: If there is no restriction on $n,a_k$ to be positive, there are infinite solutions. Make the sum of the first $k-1$ numbers $L$, where $L$ is however large you want and then set $a_k=n-L$.

Comment: It looks like you are interested in counting [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of a number.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I want to count the partitions in $k$ sets ($k$ fixed)

Comment: Look at [partitions with restricted part size or number of parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts).